# How to use sort_by when you have a nil value and multiple sorts

Tags: ruby

I have an array of calls that I would like to sort by scheduled_date first and then triggered_date second.

```
calls.sort_by! { |call| [call.scheduled_date, call.triggered_date] }
```

Because triggered_date is sometimes a nil value, I get the error
`#<ArgumentError: comparison of Array with Array failed>`

How can I sort this to account for nil values?  I've googled examples but can't find something similar to what I have. For example, I tried

```
calls.sort_by! { |call| [call.scheduled_date, call.triggered_date] } rescue nil

calls.sort_by! { |call| [call.scheduled_date, call.triggered_date] || call.scheduled_date }
```

But they don't work. I've seen `<=>` used for sort_by but not sure how to use it in this scenario where there are multiple sorts. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How would you like the `nil` values treated? Do you want then to be sorted before or after their non-`nil` counterparts e.g. should `nil` be "1900-01-01" or "9999-12-31"

Comment: Good question. Now that I think about it - if `triggered_date` is nil then I want to use `scheduled_date.end_of_day` as a replacement.

Comment: Oh. Then ignore the answer I just posted and try
`calls.sort_by! { |call| [call.scheduled_date, call.triggered_date || call.scheduled_date.end_of_day ] }` or something similar?

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you! I guess I couldn't figure out the syntax. :)

Comment: I updated my answer, in case you want to accept this as a solution. Good job @engineersmnky for asking the right question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a preferred replacement value for the possibly missing `triggered date`, which could be `call.scheduled_date.end_of_day` as you mentioned in a comment, you can do the following:

```
calls.sort_by! { |call| [call.scheduled_date, call.triggered_date || call.scheduled_date.end_of_day] }
```

Then the second entry of the array will be `triggered_date` if present and `call.scheduled_date.end_of_day` if the `triggered_date` is `nil`.

*Old answer:*

If you want the `nil`-part to just be ignored by your sorting (with the effect that those entries with `triggered_date == nil` are considered "smaller" than those with present `triggered_date`, you can just do the following:

```
calls.sort_by! { |call| [call.scheduled_date, call.triggered_date].compact }
```

`compact` removes `nil` values from an array. Thus, the calls without `triggered_date` only have a size 1 array for comparison while the others have size 2. Shortness seems to win here, so these are sorted in front of any other.

Take care though if `scheduled_date` may be `nil`, too! Then this approach can lead to really weird results.

*edited:* Added solution if possible fallbacks are known